# How to use output of Overpass API

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overpass-turbo

I have extracted way data for Railways over one country with [out:json], now how can I use this data to get all ways on google earth or QGIS? I am very new to this.

```
( area["ISO3166-1:alpha2"="PK"];) ->.a;
        way["railway"]
          (area.a);
         (._;>;);
 out body;
```

Comment: Best is to install a plugin called QuickOSM in QGIS and post your query there.

Comment: Thanks I have already added QuickOSM, I didnt notice that option is available to export data in various formats in overpass GUI

Comment: cross-post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/74136/how-to-use-output-of-overpass-api